# Why does it not show when I will be eligible for war?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I left a clan that was in the middle of a war, when I joined another clan it showed that I was not eligible for war. My clan war shield was grey and had the red bar below it but when I went to my profile it did not show when I would be eligible for war.

I asked everybody I knew and they didn't know what it was. Will this fix over time or do you think my profile is broken?

Comment: if you dont know what i mean please tell me

Answer (score 1):

According to the [FAQ](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ)

> **What happens if I leave a clan during a clan war?**
>   
>   After a leader or co-leader presses the “Start War” button, you are free to leave, join other clans and return to the clan to continue participating in the clan war. Your war base will remain in the war map even if you leave, so leaving a clan will not affect an ongoing war.
>   
>   However, you cannot participate in more than one clan war at a time. If you leave a clan while participating in a clan war, you will not be able to participate in any other clan wars until that previous war has ended. Other players will be able to see that you are still part of an unfinished war by checking your profile. You will be marked as ineligible for war until the previous clan war has concluded.

So since you was apart of a clan when it first entered a war and left for another clan after you became ineligible to join a new war. as the above quote says this should be resolved after the clan war has ended

Comment: thanks, that really helps! Good to know my profile isn't broken. Lol

Comment: **-1** | Does not answer the question: He's asking why timer stating why he's not seeing the timer that tells him when he'll become eligible for war.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a glitch in the timer appearing in some profiles. I have seen it several  times and it may show for some clan mates while not showing for others. It has been going on now for a while.